# Android Studio referencing classes in an AAR published to local maven repo

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem in Android Studio (3.1.2) referencing classes in an AAR published to my local maven repo.

I have successfully published an AAR file to my local maven repo and included it in a project that needs to use the AAR following this article:

https://medium.com/@kuassivi/tip-work-with-third-party-projects-locally-with-gradle-961d6c9efb02

Basically I have added a reference to mavenLocal() in the top level project in the repositories sections of buildscript and all projects. I have also added a reference to the AAR in the app gradle build (i.e. implementation groupid:artifactid:version). I have not done anything more than this.

If I do a gradle rebuild within Android Studio, everything compiles fine  but if I edit a file that references classes in the AAR, the IDE cannot resolve the references.

When I do find class (i.e. cmd o), the IDE correctly finds the class within the classes.jar of the AAR and decompiles it.

I am guessing that this is happening partly because it cannot pick up the source jar that I published alongside the aar file to the local maven repo.

How do I get the IDE to pick up the source files and reference the classes in the AAR correctly? I would prefer to do this via a change in the gradle scripts rather than via an IDE wizard, if that is possible.

After more digging, I have discovered that the use of the maven repo is irrelevant because it is picking up the AAR file from the gradle cache in ~/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1 not from the maven local repo. I can also include the sources files using "implementation com.company:artifact-name:0.8:sources". There is a good information here:

https://www.alonsoruibal.com/my-gradle-tips-and-tricks/

However Android Studio still cannot recognise the imports and though compilation works, the imports are marked in red in the editor. I guess there must be some magic with gradle that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a simple example on github here:

https://github.com/jmc420/kotlin_examples

In the multiproject folder there are 2 separate projects, one called "nested" which contains an android library project called "multiprojectlibrary" which "nested" references via a grade include.

The "multipleprojectlibrary" uses the maven publish plugin to publish the aar to mavenLocal via the command gradle publishToMavenLocal.

In the "independent" project "multipleprojectlibrary" is a dependency which is read from mavenLocal.

The "nested" project works reliably.

Using mavenLocal in the "independent" project seems very unreliable. Sometimes the "independent" project correctly uses the mavenLocal "multipleprojectlibrary" but when you make an update and publish again, the "independent" project starts using a copy of "multipleprojectlibrary" in .gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1.

There seem to be 2 issues. One is that the "New Project" menu option of Android Studio only allows you to make an app; you can only make an Android Library via the "New Module", which puts the library as a sub project of an app. An option to create a "New Library" would solve this.

The other issue is that it is not clear how the maven local repo and the gradle cache interact. They seem to get out of sync and sync gradle does not seem to sync the gradle cache with the mavenLocal repo.